# inappropriate inbound web traffic with strange query parameters: srcid, srctid, erid, trid, linkid, isbbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, query-string, web-traffic

I am seeing some strange inappropriate inbound traffic with query parameters not related to the operation of my website.

I am terming these inbounds as "inappropriate" because they do not confirm to RFC-3986. Specifically, you will note they are missing the question mark (?) character which is required by the spec to separate the path from the query.

As such, they crash on my back-end (which is Rails 4.1, but I don't think that's relevant to the question).

Does anyone know where these might be coming from so I can report this error to the external site? (Obviously I cannot fix them on the server because Rails expects a properly formed URI)

Note in the examples below I have changed my domain to example.com but the rest of the URL remains intact as reported by the server logs.

```
https://www.example.com/c/heeleb&srcid=1787980&srctid=1&erid=119893333&trid=13158727-4e98-40db-91cf-743f68bd6124
https://www.example.com/c/heeleb&srcid=1787980&srctid=1&erid=119893333&trid=13158727-4e98-40db-91cf-743f68bd6124&linkid=22645711&isbbox=1
https://www.example.com/c/heeleb&srcid=1787980&srctid=1&erid=119893333&trid=13158727-4e98-40db-91cf-743f68bd6124
https://www.example.com/c/heeleb&srcid=1787980&srctid=1&erid=119890326&trid=d9f3e066-c82e-4e84-ba71-2b7fdc9a3b9b
```

Answer (score 0):

One mitigation would be to configure your web server to deny such requests before they hit the Rails stack.

For example, in `nginx` one could `deny all` traffic on a `location` matching a pattern with *heeleb&srcid*.  Other production web servers have similar configuration.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not really interested mitigating the crash (it is not the problem). What we're trying to figure out is where these are coming from so we can shut down the links on the remote site if possible.